# How to call the shell script from another shell script?

Tags: shell

I have written 2 scripts which opens the vncviewer of 2 hosts.and i have another 1 script that calls both the scripts.but when I call the main script the 1st vncviewer opens and after closing the window, the 2nd vncviewer is opening..but I want to run both scripts simultaneously..how to do this?

Here are the scripts involved:

22.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 
# 
host='192.168.2.22' 
vncviewer $host --viewonly
```

25.sh

```
#!/bin/sh 
# 
host='192.168.2.25' 
vncviewer $host --viewonly
```

main script that calls 2 scripts

```
#!/bin/sh 
# 
./22.sh 
./25.sh 
sh -x 22.sh & 
sh -x 25.sh &
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to background the first invocation of `vncviewer`. Use `&` after the command for this.

Comment: yes i did that.but it is running and not going to 2nd script until 1st window is closed.

Comment: @chandan it would be better if you showed us the two scripts.

Comment: 22.sh
#!/bin/sh
#
host='192.168.2.22'
vncviewer $host --viewonly


25.sh
#!/bin/sh
#
host='192.168.2.25'
vncviewer $host --viewonly

main script that calls 2 scripts
#!/bin/sh
#
./22.sh
./25.sh

sh -x 22.sh & 
sh -x 25.sh &

Comment: @chandan I integrated these scripts in your question but I am not sure my rendering of the main script corresponds to reality - please check and edit if needed!